# What is the probability of a sum of random variables?

Tags: probability

Independent identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{20}$ takes only the values 2 and 3, while the value 3 is taken with a probability of 0.2. Find the probability that the sum of these random variables will be 46.

My attempts were unsuccessful. As I understand it, you need to go through all the options?

Comment: Well, the first thing is to determine how many of the variables have to come up $3$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, this is the problem. I do not know the answer

Comment: Well, try to figure it out.  A little effort is all that is needed.  Let $a$ be the number of variables that come up $2$ and $b$ the number that come up $3$.  Use the given information to get two equations that $a,b$ must satisfy.

Comment: @lulu The answer is $B(14;20,0.8)$. $a = 14$ and $b = 6$. Is it right?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure of your notation.  You are right about $a,b$.  But you need $14$ of them to come up $2$ and the probability of coming up $2$ is $.8$, not $.2$

Comment: @lulu a typo, sorry

Comment: @heiverjust That's a fine attempt in the comments. If you can add these attempts to the question post it will be more prominent and count as further context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_i = X_i-2$. Now you have random variables $\{Y_i, \; i=1,\ldots,20\}$ which take values from the set $\{0, 1\}$, with $\mathbb{P}(Y_i = 0) = 0.8$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y_i=1) = 0.2$.

$\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i = \sum_{i=1}^{20} (Y_i+2) = \sum_{i=1}^{20} Y_i + 20 = 46 \implies \sum_{i=1}^{20} Y_i = 6$.

For the $\{Y_i\}s$ to sum to 6, exactly 6 of them must take on the value 1. You can use the binomial formula here:

$\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^{20} Y_i = 6) = \mathbb{P}(6 \{Y_i\}s \; \text{are 1}) = {20 \choose 6}(0.2)^6\cdot (0.8)^{14}$

Answer (score 0):

A trick: $20$ variables taking values $2/3$ and summing to $46$ is the same as $20$ variables taking values $0/1$ and summing to $6$. Hence the probability is $B(6;20,0.2)$ (Binomial law).